# Uploading files to S3 bucket using CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I am attempting to upload a file to a S3 bucket created using CDK, however i am consistently running into the same error even using the example code provided by AWS.

Here is the stack.

```
export class TestStack extends cdk.Stack {
    public readonly response: string;

    constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const websiteBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'WebsiteBucket', {
            websiteIndexDocument: 'index.html',
            publicReadAccess: true,
        });
        new s3deploy.BucketDeployment(this, 'DeployWebsite', {
            sources: [s3deploy.Source.asset('./website-dist')],
            destinationBucket: websiteBucket,
            destinationKeyPrefix: 'web/static' // optional prefix in destination bucket
        });

    }
}
```

Here is the main bin as requested

```
const app = new cdk.App();

new TestStack(app, "TestStack", {
  env: {
    account: '123456789',
    region: 'us-east-1',
  }
});
```

The `destinationBucket` provides the following error inside visual studio code and when running npm build

`Property 'env' is missing in type 'Bucket' but required in type 'IBucket'.`

From what i can tell the env relates to the resource environment described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.ResourceEnvironment.html

I cannot figure out how to provide this to the bucket object as it doesn't seem to appear on the available input props described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3.Bucket.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass `env` into the Bucket Stack props.

Code snippet:

This should be located under `bin` folder when you decalre stacks.

```js
const myEnv = {
    account: '123456789',
    region: 'us-east-1',
  };
  
const App = new cdk.App();

new S3Stack(App, 'S3Stack',{env: myEnv});
```

Comment: The env is being passed to the stack but the websiteBucket still does not appear to have it. Is there a way to manually assign the env to the bucket?

Comment: Not as much as i can tell.. i have a stack which upload files to S3 and it's working like that

Comment: @VincentYeadon would you mind uploading your stack to Github so I could test it?

Comment: There really isn't much going on here i am literally using base code examples to try and get it to work,

Comment: Can you tell the CDK version ?

Comment: CDK version in package.json is ^1.59.0 so should be the newest version, the code has also been uploaded

Answer (score 0):

You should probably configure your environment for the CLI which is decribed [in the cli guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cli.html#cli-environment)